# Assign shortcut to Lock Camera to View

Tags: interface, shortcut

Instead of pressing <kbd>N</kbd>, opening the shelf, scrolling down and searching for the option *Lock Camera to View*, and then check mark. Can I create a keyboard a shortcut for *lock camera to view*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to User Pereferences/Input tab/3D View/3D View (Global)
2. There is no entry for "Lock Camera to View", so we will add a new one.
3. Click "Add New"
4. Open the "none" line that was created
5. In the text field which says "none", type: **wm.context_toggle**, and press ENTER
6. A new text field labelled "Context Attributes" appears. Type: **space_data.lock_camera**, and press ENTER
7. Define the shortcut. (Some more trial and error could be necessary to find a free one). The shortcut should work already.
8. Don't forget to also press "Save User Settings" in the User Preferences window.

In the following screenshot I just added the shortcut Ctrl-K:

[image]

Also see [this](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?274204-Add-shortcut-if-not-exist) blenderartists thread.

Answer (score 4):

Today with 2.81 it's even easier.
Just click RMB on "Lock Camera to View" and "Change Shortcut".
Then choose whatever combination you want.
[image]