# Why does EEVEE take More time when it is rendered from the button than viewing in the actual viewport?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Why does EEVEE take More time when it is rendered from the button than viewing in the actual viewport? I mean when you pan around in the rendered mode in EEVEE it takes no time to render it to the viewport but when you hit the render button from the menu, it takes some time and renders it frame by frame. 
Other than that im loving 2.8 and EEVEE...

Comment: just like with cycles, eevee offers separate quality settings for viewport and render. one of them is the sample count. another reason could be that your camera resolution is bigger than the viewport, so more pixels have to be rendered.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) Can you guide me about adjusting the camera resolution to match the viewport's? and is it possible to pan the camera around using the the normal viewport pan around methods. I mean without selecting the camera first then pressing G and then moving it around. Thank you.

Comment: there is no way to magically match them. for rendering needs, one sets the output pixels as required. to manipulate the camera using viewport navigation, see cegatons question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68996/assign-shortcut-to-lock-camera-to-view

Answer (score 1):

Because viewport sampling is lower even with eevee. Also, viewport has lower resolution.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Answers usually try to give a more elaborate explanation why things happen. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) thoroughly