# How to render in almost real-time (eevee)?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

The animation is played very smoothly at 20-24 frames per second (fps) in the viewport.

This means it takes about 1/20 seconds to render one frame. That's a tiny fraction of a second.

When I press F12 to render, It takes 20 seconds to render a single frame. That's x400 increase in the rendering time of a frame!

I reduced the number of rendering samples to be less than the number of the viewport samples and reduces some other things that may affect the rendering speed but it still takes about 5 seconds to render a single frame. For me, This is still too much given that my PC was able to play the animation in real-time.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112597/why-does-eevee-take-more-time-when-it-is-rendered-from-the-button-than-viewing-i

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for providing the link to that question. I did an experiment based on that. I calculated my viewport dimensions roughly. Viewport takes about a quarter of the area of my screen. My screen resolution is 1280*1024. This means the viewport resolution is 320*256. I also set the rendering samples to be 8 samples only (viewport is 16). The result is the rendering time is still high 1.20 seconds instead of 0.05 seconds (real-time).

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I think there are some other factors that mainly affect the rendering speed and I would like to know them :)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos One of the factors that I discovered is the subdivision surface modifier. I play the viewport with it disabled but I render it. This reduced the rendering time by half (0.5 seconds).