# Possible to use different shortcut commands for mouse vs drawing tablet?

Tags: shortcut

Is it possible to map different shortcuts/hotkeys for different "items"? such as mouse & keyboard vs a drawing tablet.

I would like to be able to have completely separate shortcuts, one for my drawing tablet, and one for my mouse, that allows me to pan, rotate, and zoom the camera, without overriding the shortcut for the other item.

I have been able to apply commands for my tablet with ease, and have been able to allow multiple hotkeys for one command in other programs[such as clip studio], so I am unsure if it is an option blender lacks, or if I am just overlooking something in the preference menu.

Comment: I updated my answer - turns out it is possible after all.

Comment: Ah interesting o: I was unaware the add new could be used for commands that were already created without overriding them. Honestly I completely skipped over the presets when I first looked through so both are extremely helpful. @ChristopherBennett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible - go to your keymap settings, and under `3DView` > `3DView(Global)` pick the action you want to map to. Open it up, and copy the value that is in the "action command" box.

[image: Action1]

Now, navigate to the bottom of the (3DViewGlobal) list and find the button that says "Add New". Click on the button.

[image: Action2]

Expand the new item that is added, and paste the action you copied earlier into the new "action command" box. From here, you can assign a new key input for the action (be mindful of conflicts however, search the "key bindings" box at the top if you're unsure if a key is in use)

[image: Action3]

Alternatively, another thing you could do, is save your tablet key-map settings as it's own preset - so you have one for keyboard and mouse, and one for the tablet. From there, you can toggle between them easily from the drop-down menu without "overriding" either of their settings.

[image: Preset]

Answer (score 0):

I use the "emulate 3 button mouse" setting in the user preferences preferences, so that moving in the 3D viewport is a combination of dragging the sytlus with one hand and pressing some keys with the other (rotate the view using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + dragging, zoom using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + drag).

Then I assigned a shortcut for "lock camera to view", so that once in camera view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>) I can navigate freely like I do with the rest of the 3D viewport.

[Assign shortcut to Lock Camera to View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68996/assign-shortcut-to-lock-camera-to-view)

Comment: I was already able to set up my shortcut command to pan, rotate, and zoom with my tablet mixed with a keyboard press or button press on my tablet, without the need of the "emulate 3 button mouse" setting. I tried applying it, but it does not help me with my problem. My issue is I would like to have completely separate commands for my tablet and mouse without overriding the other.